can gdal.Driver handle S3 file paths?
A project that I am working on requires me to access geometries stored in a .gdb folder with OGR/GDAL as geopandas is currently not capable of accessing M values associated with those geometries.
I've written a function which is capable of doing so and it works fine locally, however, I need to be able to run it on an AWS sagemaker notebook in the cloud. That being said, I will eventually be storing those .gdb's into S3 and accessing them with the respective URIs.
As the question says, can the OGR/GDAL drivers recognize and access S3 paths? I've seen very limited stuff on vsis3 (which comes up when searching around this topic) which is why I ask about this.
